# Filtrar palavras de ligação de elementos de frases

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer um filtro de palavras em uma string, para armazenar em uma variavel.

Gramaticalmente, são chamados de [preposições](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposi%C3%A7%C3%A3o), [circumposições](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumposi%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e [posposições](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posposi%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

São usados na ligação de elementos de uma frase.

EX:

```
$string = "o rato roeu a roupa do rei de roma"  
//aqui a função armazenando as palavras filtradas, que eu acredito que seja um array  
$novoValor = "rato roeu roupa rei roma;  
echo $novovalor;
```

Comment: É para remover quais palavras?

Comment: As palavras que fazem ligação, por exemplo: " de, em, e, a, o,", dentre outras menos importantes, mas que implantarei com o tempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize `in_array` para veriricar se a palavra que vc quer tirar existe.

```
$string = "o rato roeu a roupa do rei de roma"  ;

$frase = explode(' ',$string);
$retirar = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "de", "do");

for($x=0;$x<count($frase);$x++){
    if(!in_array($frase[$x], $retirar)){ 
        $novovalor .= $frase[$x].' ';
    }
}

echo $novovalor;
```

Comment: Uma dúvida: o array vai eliminar de dentro das palavras também? Fazendo com que "teste" fique "tst" caso eu adicione a letra 'E' no array?

Comment: Eu testei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente, agora é só eu adaptar as variáveis e adicionar as palavras ao filtro!  
Antes de exibir o novo valor com o echo, é exibido o seguinte "erro":  
Notice: Undefined variable: novovalor in C:\wamp\www\terreiro\teste.php on line 9  
Linha 9: $novovalor .= $frase[$x].' ';

Comment: declare a variável antes, recebendo vazio.

Comment: Perfeito!
Obrigado, de verdade ;)